# jQuery mobile undefined error Cordova.

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I am very new to the Cordova scene and even more so to the jQuery mobile scene. I am just trying to get my events within the app to fire and am getting frustrated because I am doing exactly what all the documents and tutorials have said to do.

here's my script layout with styles:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="js/jquery/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

jquery is version 3.0.0

Here is my index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

No matter what I have done, regardless of how I set up index.js or what version of jquery I"m using (i went all the way back to 1.10), I still get this error on load

```
query.mobile-1.4.5.js:3337 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.event.props.concat')
```

This error makes no sense to me, and I have restructured and rebuilt a simple hello world app with a click, several times and got nothing. I"m hoping someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong, or show me a fix, because nothing helps.

Comment: You gotta include cordova.js file in you html to trigger deviceready event. Check out this link - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#page-toc-source

Comment: I thank you for your help, but I have decided to go a different route other than jquery mobile. I have found angular to be far superior.

Comment: But did my solution work? Even if you move to angular based framework like Ionic, you still gotta included this file and event may be platform ready instead of device ready

Comment: Yeah but it's not an ideal set up for us, so we went a different route

Comment: Posted the answer for other's benefit. Hope its useful. Good luck Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta include cordova.js file in your html to trigger deviceready event. Check out this link - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#page-toc-source

It ensures Cordova is loaded completely before invoking its components.